# Deserialize a JSON array in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I've a JSON string of this format:

```
[{
  "record":
          {
             "Name": "Komal",
             "Age": 24,
             "Location": "Siliguri"
          }
 },
 {
  "record":
          {
             "Name": "Koena",
             "Age": 27,
             "Location": "Barasat"
          }
 },
 {
  "record":
          {
             "Name": "Kanan",
             "Age": 35,
             "Location": "Uttarpara"
          }
 }
... ...
]
```

Fields in "record" can increase or decrease.

So, I've made classes like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public string Age;
}

public class PersonList
{
    public Person record;
}
```

And trying to deserialize like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var r = ser.Deserialize<PersonList>(jsonData);
```

I'm doing something wrong. But unable to find. Can you please help?

**Update:**

Actually I was getting error "Invalid JSON Primitive: ." due to I was getting the string reading a file with this code:

```
public static bool ReadFromFile(string path, string fileName, out string readContent)
{
   bool status = true;
    
   byte[] readBuffer = null;
   try
   {
      // Combine the new file name with the path
      string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);
      readBuffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       status = false;
   }
    
   readContent = (null != readBuffer) ? Utilities.GetString(readBuffer) : string.Empty;
    
   return status;
}
```

Now I'm reading the file with this:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("E:\\Work\\Data.json"))
{
   string json = r.ReadToEnd();
   result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PersonList>>(json);
}
```

It's working fine.

Comment: How is .net supposed to know that you want a `Person` object for a javascript object named `"record"`?

Comment: If it's an option, I highly recommend using [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). Then you could just call something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(jsonData)`

Comment: The error was: Invalid JSON primitive: .

Comment: I had a similar issue till @valverij comment above fixed my issue. <List<ListsOfJsons>>

Comment: Note to future readers. ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Please ask real questions!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This should work...

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var records = new ser.Deserialize<List<Record>>(jsonData);

public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public string Location;
}
public class Record
{
    public Person record;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

This code is working fine for me,

```
var a = serializer.Deserialize<List<Entity>>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[JsonProperty("name")]
public string name { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("Age")]
public int required { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("Location")]
public string type { get; set; }
```

and Remove a "{"..,

```
strFieldString = strFieldString.Remove(0, strFieldString.IndexOf('{'));
```

DeserializeObject..,

```
   optionsItem objActualField = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<optionsItem(strFieldString);
```