# Deserialize array of array json

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize a JSON response. I have no familiarity with C#, so any help is appreciated. 
Here's the JSON.

```
{
    "Bookmark": ""
    "Items": [
        [
            {
                "Name": "Item",
                "Value": "A1233032"
            },
            ...
        ],
            {
                "Name": "Item",
                "Value": "B33032"
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

My C# code.

```
namespace Response
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Terrasoft.Core.Entities;

    public class Item {
        public string Name;
        public string Value;
    }

    public class Items {
        public List<Item> ItemList = new List<Item>();
    }

    public class ItemResponse {
        public List<Items> Items = new List<Items>();
    }
}
```

Explanations that explains very basic concepts in C# would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16857828/5533960)

Comment: Thanks will check it out!

Comment: You need an explanation of what exactly ? If you are interested in understanding how serialization / deserialization work, I would suggest [reading the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/) or this perhaps on [how to serialize and deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to)

Comment: Look for Newtonsoft Json.   And learn how to use it... Very simple.

Comment: Take a look at *[Convert JSON String To C# Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14904115/3744182)* and *[How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON object string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182)*.