# how to deserialize json object with arrays in it c#

Tags: c#

My object it looks like that

```
{"Items":[{number:8468},{}],

 "count":2}
```

I need to take for example number of item 1

my code is that and it is not working

```
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<ViewModel>>(content);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize a JSON array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856846/deserialize-a-json-array-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

The JSON here represents an object, not a collection - which is to say: the outer node is `{}`, not `[]`. As such, create a type that reflects that:

```cs
public class Foo {
    public List<Bar> Items {get;} = new List<Bar>();
    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public int Count {get;set;}
}
public class Bar {
    [JsonProperty("number")]
    public int Number {get;set;}
}
```

and use:

```cs
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a json object not json array. So your logic is failing. So first create a model like this :

```
public class Response {

    public List<Item> Items {get;set;} = new List<Item>();
    public int Count {get;set;}
}

public class Item {
    public int Number {get;set;}
}
```

and replace :

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<ViewModel>>(content);
```

with

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(content);
```