# What's causing JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted?

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

C# 10 / .NET 6 / System.Text.Json

I'm working with an API that returns as JSON response.  I'm trying to use `System.Text.Json` to deserialize the JSON response into a class.  I'm receiving a JsonException and could use help understanding what I'm doing wrong.

I call the API and store the JSON response:
`string json = await Retreive.Fetch(target);`

Here's the output of `Console.WriteLine(json)`:

```
[{"id": 1148082,"name": "TestGroup","group_type":"console_group","provisioning_guid": null,"member_count": 1,"current_risk_score": 36.3,"status": "active"},{"id": 1148788,"name": "Group2","group_type": "smart_group","provisioning_guid": null,"member_count": 9,"current_risk_score": 39.7,"status": "active"},{"id": 1148792,"name": "Group3","group_type": "smart_group","provisioning_guid": null,"member_count": 9,"current_risk_score": 39.7,"status": "active"}]
```

Here's a pretty-printed version if it helps:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1148082,
    "name": "TestGroup",
    "group_type": "console_group",
    "provisioning_guid": null,
    "member_count": 1,
    "current_risk_score": 36.3,
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "id": 1148788,
    "name": "Group2",
    "group_type": "smart_group",
    "provisioning_guid": null,
    "member_count": 9,
    "current_risk_score": 39.7,
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "id": 1148792,
    "name": "Group3",
    "group_type": "smart_group",
    "provisioning_guid": null,
    "member_count": 9,
    "current_risk_score": 39.7,
    "status": "active"
  }
]
```

Using Visual Studio 2022's Paste JSON As Classes function, I get the following class structure:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string group_type { get; set; }
    public object provisioning_guid { get; set; }
    public int member_count { get; set; }
    public float current_risk_score { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying: `Rootobject? gag = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(json);`

A JsonException is thrown:

> Unhandled exception. System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value
> could not be converted to KB4.Rootobject. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 |
> BytePositionInLine: 1.    at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type
> propertyType)    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader&
> reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack&
> state, T& value)    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1
> utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1
> json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json,
> JsonSerializerOptions options)    at KB4.Kb4.Main() in
> C:<REDACTED>\Program.cs:line 188    at
> KB4.Kb4.()

Some things I have tried:

- Changing the name of the `Rootobject` class to `GetAllGroups`
- Thinking the JSON may be somehow malformed in the response, I pasted it into a text file and load the JSON from there and then attempt deserialization again.
- Reviewed [Deserialize a JSON array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856846/deserialize-a-json-array-in-c-sharp) but that's using JavaScriptSerializer.

Neither of the above produces a different result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this  -  var gag = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Class1>>(json);

Comment: That works!  Thank you @Serge!  Can you help me understand why my original method did not work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

your Rootobject class would be working if your json starts with this

```
{ "property1": [{"id": 1148082,"name": .....] }
```

and the array had a property name. but  your json don't  have property1, so you should start to deserialize json array directly

```
Class1[] result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Class1[]>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

would it have been easier and a lil bit more straight forward to just fix the json and add your class's property1

```
tmp = Regex.Replace(Result, @"^\{(.*)", "{\"property1\":{$1");
Result = tmp;
tmp= result+"}";
result=tmp;
```

...and do the decode voodoo...

Answer (score -1):

However, as @serge pointed out, your deserialize with `Rootobject` would work if the response was with a `property1`. However, adding to what @serge mentioned, the following should also work; given that @serged used an `array` but I used a `List<T>`:

```
var response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Class1>>(json);
```