# Trying deserialize a JSON array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I have a similar issue relate in this link [Deserialize a JSON array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856846/deserialize-a-json-array-in-c-sharp)

But I can't catch the array, so if someone can take a look and tell what I'm doing wrong, I would appreciate it. This is my JSON array:

```
{
    "latitude": [
        {
            "ts": 1677055475800,
            "value": "40.480946"
        }
    ],
    "longitude": [
        {
            "ts": 1677055475800,
            "value": "-3.37441"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried the answer:

```
    class Latitud
    {
        public Device latitude;

    }
    class Longitud
    {
        public Device longitude;

    }
    class Device
    {
        public string ts { get; set; }

        public int value { get; set; }

    }

    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var mylongitude= ser.Deserialize<List<Longitud>>(jsonData);
    var mylatitude = ser.Deserialize<List<Latitud>>(jsonData);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deserialize the JSON string jsonData into the mylatitude and mylongitude variables, you are using the Deserialize<List>(jsonData) and Deserialize<List>(jsonData) methods, respectively.

However, the latitude and longitude properties in the JSON object are arrays, not objects. So you should deserialize them into a list of Coordinate objects rather than a list of Latitud or Longitud objects.

Can you please try this,

```
public class Location
{
     public List<Coordinate> latitude { get; set; }
     public List<Coordinate> longitude { get; set; }
}

public class Coordinate
{
    public long ts { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

// Deserialize the JSON string into an object
string jsonString = "Your JSON code";

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Location location = serializer.Deserialize<Location>(jsonString);


Console.WriteLine("Latitude: " + location.latitude[0].value);
Console.WriteLine("Longitude: " + location.longitude[0].value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your structure does not match the source JSON.

You need a target object to represent the whole structure. Also, your `Device` class needs to match the structure of the inner data stored in the arrays:

```
//This represents your main structure
public class SomeTargetObject
{
    public Device[] Latitude { get; set; }

    public Device[] Longitude { get; set; }
}

//This represents the inner data 
public class Device
{
    public string ts { get; set;}
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Lastly, I would recommend using `NewtonSoft` from the `Newtonsoft.Json` package to deserialize it instead:

```
var json = @"{
                ""latitude"": [
                    {
                        ""ts"": 1677055475800,
                        ""value"": ""40.480946""
                    }
                ],
                ""longitude"": [
                    {
                        ""ts"": 1677055475800,
                        ""value"": ""-3.37441""
                    }
                ]
            }";

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeTargetObject>(json);
```

`JsonConvert` can be found in the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace. Make sure to add the package.